# Orientation problem

Tags: iphone, landscape-portrait, orientation-changes

i want that my textfield should move up in any orientation.

But I am having a problem in landscape right and portrait upside down.

As when i orient it to any one of them my textfield down the view does not go up but the textfield which is on top is going up.

suggest me some solution.

below is the code that i am using for orientation.

please suggest me whole procedure if you can as i am a niwBie to iPhone development.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGRect textFieldRect=[self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
CGRect viewRect=[self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

CGFloat midLine=textFieldRect.origin.y+0.5*textFieldRect.size.height;
CGFloat numerator=midLine-viewRect.origin.y-MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION*viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat denominator=(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION-MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)*viewRect.size.height;

CGFloat heightFraction=numerator/denominator;
if(heightFraction < 0.0)
{
    heightFraction=0.0;
}
else if(heightFraction > 1.0)
{
    heightFraction=1.0;
}

CGRect viewFrame;
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation];
//code for text field editing in landscape an portrait mode

if(orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    animatedDistance=floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT*heightFraction);
}
else 
{
    animatedDistance=floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT*heightFraction);
}

if (orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    viewFrame=self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y-=animatedDistance;
}
else if(orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
    viewFrame=self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y+=animatedDistance;
}
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    viewFrame=self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.x+=animatedDistance;

}
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){

    viewFrame=self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.x-=animatedDistance;
}

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController override the - willRotateToInterfaceRotation:duration method. This message is called when the user rotates the device. In this method you can then set all your views to be placed in their proper positions. See Responding to View Rotation Events in the reference: [UIViewController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926)

you could do something like this:

```
    - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        yourView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);  //and set the proper coordinate for this view in this orientation
}
```

and then do it for all your views that are not placed correctly when rotating

Comment: but i dont know how in my landscape right and upside down mode...the text field down the view is getting covered with keyboard...what settings i will write in - willRotateToInterfaceRotation:duration method?...please explain me by seeing my code above of textFieldDidBeginEditing method...O_o

Comment: Actually In my iPhone app i used the above code to lift the view in order to show the textfield above the keyboard. My application support all four interface orientations. I use the following code to lift the view. Problem here is that it only works for portrait orientation. Is there any way to implement the correct lifting in all four orientations